# Unexpected Values while generationing Pytorch Sparse COO Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix

I've been trying to create a sparse tensor using

new_vertices_sparse = torch.sparse_coo_tensor((new_vertices,torch.ones(len(new_vertices),dtype=int),size)

However, there seems to be an issue with how I am generating it, or how I am retrieving its values.

Using the print function we find,
print(new_vertices_sparse)

```
tensor(indices=tensor([[10, 10, 10,  ..., 12, 12, 11],
                       [ 5,  4,  3,  ...,  3,  2,  2],
                       [ 4,  5,  4,  ...,  6,  7,  8]]),
       values=tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
       size=(15, 15, 15), nnz=548, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
```

as expected.

However if we try to retrieve the values, we find

print(new_vertices_sparse.coalesce().values())

```
tensor([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2,
        2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2,
        2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4,
        2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 3])
```

Comment: Standard practice with sparse matrices, is to sum duplicate `coo` coordinates.  Does the `coalesce` say anything about that?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html#sparse-uncoalesced-coo-docs